# Mysql interval is not working after new year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I am making a query on a website that i am working on that selects the top 1 user based on number of count it figures in a table between a specific interval of 1 year or 365 days it was working well last week but today i tried it and it is not working. I made some tests and i found out the problem is with the interval section. When i run the query it gives 0 results back. So I need your help please

```
SELECT user_posted_to, COUNT(*)
FROM activity_log_table 
WHERE post_type = 'discussion'
   AND activity_type = 'Like'
   AND activity_timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 365 DAY
   AND activity_timestamp <= CURRENT_DATE 
GROUP BY user_posted_to
ORDER BY COUNT(user_posted_to) DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `activity_timestamp`?

Comment: it is an int (18)

Comment: @juergend you mean the problem is from the wamp server ?

Comment: You should change your data type to `date` and try again.

Comment: that would cause a big change to the whole site code, can this be done using timestamp variable and going around the mysql query so eliminate the interval ?

Comment: @firasprogrammer I can't understand how it was _working_ in 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `activity_timestamp` is an INT, a unix timestamp, you must use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to convert dates to unix timestamps:

```
AND activity_timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 365 DAY)
AND activity_timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: @firasprogrammer . . . If this works, then your previous code never actually worked.

Comment: but it was working because i got the same result as now but that was before 1 1 2019

Comment: @firas I am guessing you were getting wrong results. E.g. `2019-01-01` would be treated as a number `20190101` and compared with unix times.